# using jQuery :not selector to exclude list item class

Tags: jquery, selector

I have an image slider, and I need to select all slide captions except one that has a given class, as defined by the slider API.

I have a variable curSlide that shows the current slide number (index value) in a slider.

```
var curSlide = $('#slides').superslides('current');
```

I would like to hide all of the captions that are NOT currently being shown. The captions have the same class as the index value with a cap before it. For example cap0, cap1, cap2, etc.

```
var notClass= $("#captions:not(li.cap" + curSlide));
notClass.animate({'opacity' : 0}, 200);
```

This is not working. How to I write this selector correctly as a variable?

Comment: The selector is `:not(...)` you are creating `:not(...` (missing closing parenthesis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing `)` in your selector:

```
var notClass= $("#captions:not(li.cap" + curSlide + ")");
```

You were actually selecting `:not(` as Felix mentioned, while you want `:not()`.

Comment: this is selecting the entire unordered list. I want it to select the list items that dont have the class

Comment: does this work:  var notClass= $("#captions li:not(.cap" + curSlide + ")");